# ffmpeg randomly stops recording rtmp stream

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, rtmp

I am trying to record a rtmp stream using ffmpeg. On the whole it records the stream fine but every so often it stops recording the stream and when I then go to record it again, it will only record around a second or 2 before it stops again. This usually goes on for like 10-15mins. In this time if I want to record the stream, I would have to manually record 1-2 seconds each time. This sounds like it is a server issue - perhaps there is a mechanism that cuts off the stream every few seconds.

In the case where the stream cuts off, is there a way to keep trying and recording all of these 1-2 second segments rather than me doing it manually? Doing it manually creates gaps in the recording due to the time taken to connect and record the stream. I even tried running the command in a loop but even with that there are gaps in the video.

The code I am using to record the stream is as follows:

```
ffmpeg -i "rtmp://example.com/stream?id=12345" -vcodec copy -acoded copy "output.mp4"
```

When it is recording fine and cuts off the first time, there is no error given. It's like the stream came to an end so it stops recording. The subsequent times where I can only record 1-2 seconds are the same - there is no error

As there are no error messages such as timeout or connection errors, I cannot even run flags on the command to retry recording.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, no idea yet about a solution